# Filter every column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with three tables right now : equipements and equipements_statistics that contains the statistics of each equipements and finally stats that contains all type of statistics.

To retrieve an equipement on a filter I'm doing this query :

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `equipement`
INNER JOIN `equipement_stats` ON `equipement_stats`.`id_equipement` = `equipement`.`id_equipement`
INNER JOIN `stats` ON `stats`.`id_stats` = `equipement_stats`.`id_stats`
WHERE
    `stats`.`id_stats` IN(1068, 1069)
GROUP BY
    `equipement`.`id_equipement`
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT stats.id_stats) = 1
LIMIT 10
```

Tables are like this :

equipement

```
+---------------+-----------------+
| id_equipement | name_equipement |
+---------------+-----------------+
|             1 | one             |
|             2 | two             |
|             3 | three           |
+---------------+-----------------+`
```

equipement_stats

```
+---------------+-----------+---------------+
| id_equipement | id_stats  | random_number |
+---------------+-----------+---------------+
| 1             | 2         | 0             |
| 1             | 4         | 0             |
| 1             | 1069      | 1             |
| 1             | 8         | 0             |
| _____________ | _________ | _____________ |
| 2             | 1070      | 2             |
| 2             | 1069      | 3             |
| 2             | 20        | 0             |
| 2             | 40        | 0             |
+---------------+-----------+---------------+
```

If stats are 1068 or 1069 I must filter them on the column `random_number` but `random_number` value can be different for 1070 and 1069. How to look only for a precise id_stats with a precise random_number?

In my case for example, I would like to filter on equipements that has the stats 1070 with random_number 2 and stats 1069 with random_number 3 as the 2nd entry.

Thanks you for helping!

Comment: That query is invalid. You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to filter tuples is this:

```
WHERE (equipement_stats.id_stats, equipement_stats.random_number) IN ( (1068,2) , (1069,3) )
```

Comment: So that was that obvious, thanks you very much I learnt something

Comment: You are welcome. The other option is to use `AND` and `OR` with appropriate parentheses: `WHERE (equipement_stats.id_stats = 1068 AND equipement_stats.random_number = 2) OR (equipement_stats.id_stats = 1069 AND equipement_stats.random_number = 3) `. Quite simple. But I like tuples better.